# Style the default "No video source" / "No video permissions" black rectangle

Tags: ios, css, safari, quaggajs

When the user is prompted for a permission on Safari, the video element is shown as a black rectangle with a strikethrough play button. How do I change this element's styling? Does it have a specific ID / class / tag?

I'm using Quagga JS as a barcode scanner. AFAIK Quagga creates a `video` element, then asks for camera permission. The optimal result would be to hide the element using `display:none;`, but I can't think of any way to accomplish this. I need the element to display the camera feed once the scanner has its permission, but before that it should either paint the screen black or be hidden.

[image: safari video css issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by hiding it via JavaScript and showing it once the Quagga Feedback has finished. Note that a pure CSS solution would be much prettier.

```
// Hide the preview before it's fully initialised.
    $('#videoBoundingBox').hide();
    Quagga.init({
        inputStream: {
            name: "Live",
            type: "LiveStream",
            target: document.querySelector('#videoBoundingBox')
        },
        decoder: {
            readers: [
                "code_128_reader",
                "ean_reader"
            ]
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setResult(err);
            err = err.toString();
            if (err.search("NotFoundError")) {
                // No camera found. The user is probably in an office environment.
                // Redirect to previous orders or show a background image of sorts.
            } else if (err.search("NotAllowedError")) {
                // The user has blocked the permission request.
                // We should ask them again just to be sure or redirect them.
            } else {
                // Some other error.
            }


            return;
        }
        // Hide the preview before it's fully initialised.
        $('#videoBoundingBox').show();
        setResult("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
        console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
        Quagga.start();
        initializeQuaggaFeedback();
    });
```